# How does EAFP avoid the risk of a TOC/TOU race condition in LBYL?

Tags: error-handling, race-condition, control-flow

One of the explanations for preferring EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission) over LBYL (Look Before You Leap) is that LBYL is vulnerable to TOC/TOU race conditions (time-of-check to time-of-use) in concurrent programs. A relatively harmless example in Python:

```
class Ratio:
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.n = numerator
        self.d = denominator

    def LBYL_divide(self):
        if self.d != 0:          # check
                                 # another thread can change self.d
            return self.n/self.d # use
        else:
            return "NA"

    def EAFP_divide(self):
        try:
            return self.n/self.d
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return "NA"
```

I interpreted examples like these to mean that in EAFP, there's no opportunity for another thread to sneak in between the check and use because they're done on the same line/step. But I'm under the impression that some condition must be checked before an exception is thrown; in this example, `/` must have checked if `self.d != 0` to know to throw a `ZeroDivisionError`. Why can't another thread sneak in after those checks and cause problems?